# MBPr 13" - still warm and out in the cold

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

I have been using my Macbook Pro Retina 13" (late 2012 model) for a few hours, shut it down, put it in my laptop bag and went outside. It was pretty cold, I could see my exhaled breath condense; I guess it was pretty cold - probably close to 0 degrees celsius.

The computer was still warm when I went outside. When I finally came back home (about 30-40 minutes later) the computer remained relatively warm to the touch (although you could tell that it was outside in the cold). I haven't yet turned it on.

**Question 1:** Could this cause damage to internal components? I am aware of condensation damage, but this time it's the other way around - the computer was already warm when I went outside to cold weather.

**Question 2:** Suppose we have the usual scenario - out in the cold and then back home in warm temperature. How long should I wait before turning the computer on? I once tried opening the screen and exhaling directly on it and I saw my breath on the display, but it disappeared immediately and I turned the computer on promptly afterwards. Could this also cause condensation/corrosion damage?